# Hibernate NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-search

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate Search with Spring Data JPA, so I wrote a sample code to test it.

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Place> findAll() {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

    QueryBuilder builder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Place.class).get();

    double centerLatitude = 0d;
    double centerLongitude = 0d;
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = builder
            .spatial()
            .within(100, Unit.KM)
            .ofLatitude(centerLatitude)
            .andLongitude(centerLongitude)
            .createQuery();

    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
            fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Place.class);

    em.close();
    return jpaQuery.getResultList();
}
```

And I'm getting exception with following stacktrace.

```
2016-06-13 17:34:30 INFO  LogHelper:31 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-06-13 17:34:30 INFO  Version:37 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.6.Final}
2016-06-13 17:34:30 INFO  Environment:213 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-06-13 17:34:30 INFO  Environment:317 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-06-13 17:34:30 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-06-13 17:34:31 INFO  Dialect:154 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-06-13 17:34:31 INFO  Version:30 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
2016-06-13 17:34:31 INFO  Version:26 - HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.5.3.Final
2016-06-13 17:34:32 INFO  SchemaUpdate:105 - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-06-13 17:34:32 WARN  ConfigContext:346 - HSEARCH000075: Configuration setting hibernate.search.lucene_version was not specified: using LUCENE_CURRENT.
//...    

[localhost-startStop-1] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in pl.project.api.config.RepositoryConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
//...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DefaultLockFactoryCreator.createLockFactory(DefaultLockFactoryCreator.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.getLockFactory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.createFSIndex(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.create(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManagers(IndexManagerHolder.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:530)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at     org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 21
```

I'm juggling with my dependencies and their versions but nothing changes.
My dependencies

```
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm also using `Spring Data JPA` from ReleaseTrain (`Hopper-SR1`) so it's `Spring Data JPA 1.10.1`

My Place.class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Indexed
@Spatial
public class Place implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8379536848917838560L;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "place_id")
    private Long id;

    //...
    @Longitude
    private Double lng;

    @Latitude
    private Double lat;
    //...
    }
```

[Here is my RepositoryConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762617/configuring-hibernate-search-with-entitymanager)
[mvn dependency:tree of my parent module](http://pastebin.com/DwA7r4Q1)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622885/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance

Comment: I know that is probably dependency issue, but as I wrote, I'm juggling with versions and dependencies with no result. How can I track what is causing the problem

Comment: Something to do with your hibernate annotations jar. Try removing it, if it exists in your dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately I never had something like that in my dependencies

Comment: But i found that something like that i had in logs `INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}`

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuild again. Check the build path. I think that the two jars are conflicting and hence this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are pulling in a non-compatible version of Lucene. Can you share the output of running `mvn dependency:tree`? Hibernate Search 5.5 works with Lucene 5.3 atm.

Comment: Gunnar (who is on the Hibernate dev team!) is certainly right. The error means you're having some incompatible dependencies; the ones you listed are correct but you're probably including more because of other dependencies. Hibernate Search 5.5 works with Hibernate ORM 5.0.x and 5.1.x (NOT with 5.2.x), and with Apache Lucene 5.3.x, 5.4.x and 5.5.x (Not 6.0)

Comment: I kicked `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:1.5.2` from my project because it has old version of `org.apache.lucene:lucene-*`. Now it's finally works.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear. Btw. if you'd like to use Elasticsearch, you might be interested in the [latest Beta](http://in.relation.to/2016/05/24/ElasticsearchintegrationReachesBeta1/) of Hibernate Search 5.6, which brings transparent integration of Elasticsearch into Hibernate/JPA applications.