# Unable to guess FieldBridge in Search 5.5. Unindexed Fields

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

Versions:

- **Hibernate-Core:** 5.2.5.Final
- **Hibernate-Search:** 5.5.5.Final

Having the following mappings:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "scanresult")
public class ScanResult
{
    @Id
    private ScanResultKey id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}

@Embeddable
public class ScanResultKey implements Serializable
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "eA", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private EntityA entA;

    //others...
}
```

I have read in previous posts that this was an issue in `Search 4.4` (when having composite id and foreign relations), but this should be fixed in `5.5`. So apparently it is my fault. But I can't figure out what could I do wrong

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000135: Unable to guess FieldBridge for id in entities.keys.ScanResultKey
```

**Note:** I only need one field(`name`) to be indexed

Could you please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The main problem here is the assumption that you don't need to use the `FieldBridge`. Are you able to point a finger to what led you into this misunderstanding? I'd be happy to try improve the documentation and the error message.

Comment: @Sanne thanks for your reply. It's more me being stupid, rather than documentation problem. My thought was since Composite Key Class is `Serializable`, `Hibernate Search` can write/recreate it to/from Lucene index. And after coming with this solution I understood that my assumption was wrong. But I'm not an expert by any means, so this thought is not really worth be taken into account. Thanks again, Sanne

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback! I'll still see if we can improve the clarity of the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, Since this question got interest near to none, according to view count, here is, briefly, the way I managed (hopefully) to resolve the problem (Please, correct me if you know more)

- Verify modules' versions compatibility

According to one of the commenters in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794566/hibernate-nosuchfielderror-instance) SO question, not all (even latest) versions are compatible with each other. For example:

> Hibernate Search 5.5 works with Hibernate ORM 5.0.x and 5.1.x (NOT
>   with 5.2.x), and with Apache Lucene 5.3.x, 5.4.x and 5.5.x (Not 6.0)

Stated by: [Sanne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563323/sanne)

This is not a fix to this particular problem, but might save from other issues

- Create a `FieldBridge` for Composite Key implementing
  `TwoWayFieldBridge`

  public class ScanResultBridge implements TwoWayFieldBridge
- Add annotation to Entity Class, specifying the implementation of Bridge

  @FieldBridge(impl = ScanResultBridge.class)
  private ScanResultKey id;

Comment: Your solution is correct as any non-trivial Id will need a custom FieldBridge. To use Hibernate ORM `5.2.x` get Hibernate Search `5.7.x`: http://hibernate.org/search/downloads/